# Can a XTR 2016 di2 bracket axle unit fit in XT 2016 rear derailleur?

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear

I have recently lost my bracket axle unit of my XT 2016 m8000 rear derailleur. My friend will be mailing me his XTR 2016 di2 bracket axle unit. Is it compatible/will it fit? I just wanted to know before i buy an after market bracket axle unit from(Goat Link by wolftooth components).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the Shimano Exploded View [PDF for the Di2 mech (pdf download)](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/ev/EV-RD-M9050-3817A.pdf):

And for your [XT one (pdf download)](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/ev/EV-RD-M8000-3859.pdf):

[image]

What you can see from those documents is that the Bracket Axle Unit aka B-Axle is very different between XT and XTR Di2.

I would expect them not to be compatible.

Comment: thanks for this! you've saved me and my friend the hassle...